# Port 53 Apparently Blocked When Attempting to Ping it From One Virtual Machine To Another On Same Network

Tags: ubuntu, dns, port, virtual, ping

So basically I am just trying to ping configure one Virtual Machine within my home network to act as a DNS server for another virtual machine within my home network.  Everything worked as it was supposed to 1 time.  I used the dig command and saw that the IP address of my virtual machine was used as a DNS server.  However, for some reason, it just stopped working later on and now I am noticing that I cannot even ping port 53 from any virtual machine in my network to any other virtual machine in my network.  I can send normal ICMP pings just fine.  But I get 100% packet loss when I try to ping port 53.  The ufw firewall is completely disabled.  Can anyone help with at least making the ping to port 53 work?  I am pinging the port (on my own network) with the following command "sudo ping 10.0.2.5 53"

Answer (score 1):

- how exactly are you 'pinging the port'?
- check on DNS server whether it is listening on udp/53 and tcp/53 with `netstat -tulpn`
- if it's not listening then DNS service is not running - depending on your DNS server type you have to check it typically `systemctl status named` and just for sure `systemctl restart named`